# git config для нескольких разработчиков

Tags: git

Начинаю изучать гит, репозиторий использую битбакет, сразу возник вопрос:

Например подключился к боевому сайту по ssh, сделал git init в нужной директории. Настраиваю `git config user.email` и `git config user.name`

Далее все мои действия будут фиксироваться с этими данными (я правильно понимаю?).

Далее, мой коллега подключится к этому же проекту через ssh, и прописывает `git config user.email` и видит мой email.

Соответственно его действия будут фиксироваться под моими данными? Как сделать чтобы у него был свой user name и email? Если он пропишет свои данные через `git config user.email`, то перезапишет мои.

Что я не так понял?

Comment: Нашел только, что пишут про переменные среди и т.д. 
И как то там все сложно,  вроде гит и сделан для того, чтобы работала команда над проектом, как другие решают эту проблему? 

Или как то по особому принято организовать работу с гитом?

Comment: Каждый разработчик работает над проектом на своем компьютере и кладет изменения в репозиторий. На продакшене ничего не комитится, только ответственный сотрудник применяет изменения

Comment: но если очень хочется: https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/carry-git-settings.htm

Comment: `вроде гит и сделан для того, чтобы работала команда над проектом, как другие решают эту проблему?` каждый участник команды работает со своей машины и в стандартном сценарии такой проблемы нет, подробнее написал в ответе ниже

Answer (score 4):

хотя вопрос и продиктован несколько неверным пониманием того, что же такое есть [система управления версиями](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8), и по этому поводу уже [дан замечательный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/859698/178576), но…

но иногда (пусть и редко) случается необходимость работать с *git-хранилищем* двум и более пользователям из-под одной и той же учётной записи (подключаясь к машине по протоколу *ssh*).

как в такой ситуации пользователям передать команде *commit* **разные** данные (имя и почтовый адрес) о себе?

для этого можно, например, использовать переменные окружения. их четыре и все они должны иметь значения (тогда и только тогда программа *git* ими воспользуется при выполнении команды *commit*):

```
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="ваше имя"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="ваш@адр.ес"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="${GIT_AUTHOR_NAME}"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="${GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL}"
```

эти команды имеет смысл каждому из пользователей добавить в «ресурсный файл» своей оболочки. в случае, например, программы *bash* — это `~/.bashrc`.

чтобы они при подключении «попали» в экземпляр оболочки, запускаемый на удалённой машине, нужно:

1. в конфигурации локальной программы *ssh* указать их отправку, добавив где-нибудь в начале файла `~/.ssh/config` строку:

   ```
   sendenv GIT_*
   ```
2. в конфигурации удалённой программы *sshd* указать их приём, добавив в файл `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` строку (программу надо будет после этого перезапустить):

   ```
   acceptenv GIT_*
   ```

---

доп. чтение:

- `man git-config`
- `man git-commit-tree`
- `man ssh_config`
- `man sshd_config`

Answer (score 2):

есть понятия: репозиторий (у вас битбакет) и локальный репозиторий (который находится на вашем компе и доступен под вашим аккаунтом)

в собственно репозитории никто напрямую не правит.
код вы правите на своем локальном компьютере. и настраиваете `git config user.email`, `git config user.name` на локальном.

- первое, что вы должны сделать - клонировать к себе в локальный репозиторий файлы из общего битбакета.
- далее даете команду развернуть сами файлы из локального репозитория.
- далее правите файлы в локали.
- потом даете команду гиту, чтобы ваши
  измененные файлы сначала записал в локальный репозиторий (здесь то
  конфиг юзера и действует).
- в конце даете команду гиту, чтобы он
  синхронизировал локальный и общий репозиторий.

некоторые действия выполняются гитом в одну команду.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы на своей машине, находясь в папке репозитория введете `git config user.name "UserName"` - эта настройка сохранится в настройках вашего репозитория. Но вы не сможете это закоммитить и потом запушить на удаленный сервер. Настройки не коммитятся, они есть только в вашем репозитории и никак не могут попасть на компьютер к вашему коллеге.

Но судя по вашему вопросу вы как-то нестандартно используете гит. Похоже вы по очереди работаете с одной и той же машины.

С гитом обычно работают так - есть центральный репозиторий, на сервере, в Bitbucket например. Разработчик, который хочет что-то в этот репозиторий закоммитить, клонирует репозиторий на свою машину, настраивает свое имя и почту (и эти настройки он никак не может отправить в центральный репозиторий, они есть только в его копии), потом что-то меняет, коммитит и вот этот коммит он уже может отправить в центральный репозиторий (`git push`) что-бы его увидели остальные разработчики.