# Работа с git'ом под разными учетками

Tags: git

Как с чужого компа, на котором чужая учетка Git работающая по SSH-ключу, сделать push/pull request под своей учеткой (действие единоразовое)

Comment: Пробросить свой ssh-ключ

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а потом старый возвращать - не прикольно. Хотелось бы, как-то, просто, ввести данные своей учетки - выполнить действие и все

Comment: Так а о какой учётке вообще речь? И что должно в результате получиться?

Comment: Git ожидает ключа. Можно попытаться выполнить `SSH_AUTH_SOCK= git ...`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/859808/178576

Comment: *сделать push/pull **request*** — речь, видимо, о браузере и веб-интерфейсе типа github.com/gitlab/etc, а не о программе *git*? тогда: запускаете браузер в режиме «incognito», логинитесь и выполняете «push/pull request».

Answer (score 0, accepted):

кстати, проблема решалась так:

`git push https://_user_name:_password@github.com/_user_name/_project_name.git`